# want to update only those items in database which are filled in fxml UI. Items that are not filled should remains same in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, javafx, controller, fxml

I am new to javafx
What should i use to update(in database) only those fields that are filled in UI and rest fields should remain same in the database. How will i get to know which value to set (in UPDATE SET query)
For example: If i want to update only name for a particular personID but remain other fields same in the database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydlyy.jpg)

Comment: Build your sql string based on the textfield's length. If trim().length > 0, make it part of the sql string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, your query should only `SET` the fields you wish to change.

Suppose you have a simple database table of `Users` with the following fields:

```
user_id |first_name | middle_name | last_name
```

Now you want to update the `first_name` and `middle_name` for user #23, but leave `last_name` the same.

Your SQL query should be

```
UPDATE table_name
SET 
    first_name = 'John',
    middle_name = 'Michael'
WHERE user_id = 23;
```

The record will now be updated with the new `first_name` and `middle_name` but `last_name` will stay the same.  Only the fields you specifically `SET` in your query will be affected.

---

Therefore, in order to build your query, just check each `TextField` in your UI to see if a value has been entered/changed. Then only include those in your query.

Comment: The input is given in the UI box . How will Ui come to know which label has been changed? It will set null value to last name

Comment: You need to write the logic to determine if something has changed. The UI won't know anything unless you tell it to pay attention :)

Comment: Maybe you need to rewrite your question and clarify exactly what it is you're asking...